# Ruby Rails Devise and SAML with Office 365

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, saml

I have setup a new Rails application using devise and devise_saml_authenticatable to authenticate against Office 365.

The login unfortunately shows following error message:

```
Sign in

Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS7500522: XML element 'AuthnContextClassRef' in XML namespace 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion' in the SAML message must be a URI.
```

My config/decise.rb file looks as follows:

```
  config.saml_create_user = true
  config.saml_update_user = true
  config.saml_default_user_key = :email
  config.saml_session_index_key = :session_index
  config.saml_use_subject = true
  config.idp_settings_adapter = nil
  config.saml_configure do |settings|
    settings.assertion_consumer_service_url     = "https://localhost:3000/users/saml/auth"
    settings.assertion_consumer_service_binding = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    settings.name_identifier_format             = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"
    settings.issuer                             = "https://localhost:3000/saml/metadata"
    settings.authn_context                      = ""
    settings.idp_slo_target_url                 = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/wsfederation?wa=wsignout1.0"          
    settings.idp_sso_target_url                 = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/saml2"         
    settings.idp_cert_fingerprint               = "E4:....."
    settings.idp_cert_fingerprint_algorithm     = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"
  end
```

and the "Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL)" in the Azure configuration is set to

```
https://localhost:3000/users/saml/auth
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out: All the Devise examples have

```
settings.authn_context = ""
```

set. If I set it to

```
settings.authn_context = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password"
```

then the error disappears.